# invalid use of template-name w/o an argument list

Tags: c++, templates

This is my code I keep getting the error ./partition2.h:45:5: error: invalid use of template-name ‘fsu::Partition2’ without an argument list but i am not sure what is causing this error. Usually its because I didn't put template before my functions but I did so now I am a bit confused.

```
#include "vector.h"
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

#include <entry.h>
#include <list.h>
#include <primes.h>

namespace fsu
{
  template < typename N = size_t >
  class Partition2
    {
      public:
      explicit Partition2     ( N size );       // create singletons {0} .. {size-1}
      void     Reset         ();               // reverts to singletons
      void     Reset         ( N newsize );
      void     PushSingleton () { parent_.PushBack((N)parent_.Size()); rank_.PushBack(0); }
      void     Union         ( N x , N y ) { Link(Root(x),Root(y)); }
      bool     Find          ( N x , N y ) { return Root(x) == Root(y); }
      bool     Find          ( N x , N y ) const { return Root(x) == Root(y); }

      size_t   Size          () const { return rank_.Size(); }
      size_t   Components    () const;
      void     Display       ( std::ostream& os ) const;
      void     Dump          ( std::ostream& os ) const;

      private: // methods
      N    Root   ( N x );                // path compression changes state
      N    Root   ( N x ) const;          // no path compression
      void Link   ( N root1 , N root2 );  // union assuming arguments are roots

      private: // objects
      fsu::Vector <N> parent_;
      fsu::Vector <N> rank_;
      N comp_count;
    };

  template < typename N = size_t >
    Partition2::Partition2 ( N size) : parent_((size_t)size,0), rank_((size_t)size, 0)
    {

    }
} //fsu
```

Comment: Can you indicate which line is line 45? -_-"

Comment: Well, you should give the template a template argument list?

Answer (score 0):

For an out-of-line definition of a member of a class template, you need the template parameters after the class name.

```
  template < typename N = size_t >
    Partition2<N>::Partition2 ( N size) : // ...
    {
        // ...
    }
```

BTW, I don't recommend using `N` as the name of a type template parameter, because it's usually used for an integral (non-type) template parameter.